# Lifelog + Samsung Smartwatch

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 and I love the Lifelog. I have won a smartwatch samsung Gear S2. The problem is that I can not do Gear and Lifelog work together. There is some step-by-step I can use to configure the app with smartwatch?
thank you
Fernando

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately unless there is an app written for the Samsung Gear S2 you will not be able to pull Lifelog data using the watch.